# SWT : showing animated gif with transparent background

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to show a animated gif which has transparent background. but the result is that the background is not transparent, below is my code, what is wrong with it?

```
package amarsoft.rcp.base.widgets;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;

/**
 * 负责显示各种格式的图片
 * 
 * @author ggfan@amarsoft
 */
public class ImageViewer extends Canvas {

    protected Point origin = new Point(0, 0);
    protected Image image;
    protected ImageData[] imageDatas;
    protected Image[] images;
    protected int current;
    private int repeatCount;
    private Runnable animationTimer;
    private Color bg;
    private Display display;

    public ImageViewer(Composite parent) {
        super(parent,SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
        bg = getBackground();
        display = getDisplay();
        addListeners();
    }

    public void setImage(ImageData imageData) {

        checkWidget();

        stopAnimationTimer();
        if(imageData != null){
            this.image = new Image(display, imageData);
        }
        this.imageDatas = null;
        this.images = null;
        redraw();
    }

    /**
     * @param repeatCount
     *            0 forever
     */
    public void setImages(ImageData[] imageDatas, int repeatCount) {
        checkWidget();

        this.image = null;
        this.imageDatas = imageDatas;
        this.repeatCount = repeatCount;
        convertImageDatasToImages();
        startAnimationTimer();
        redraw();
    }

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
        checkWidget();

        Image image = getCurrentImage();
        if (image != null) {
            Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
            Rectangle trim = computeTrim(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
            return new Point(trim.width, trim.height);
        }

        return new Point(wHint, hHint);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        if (image != null)
            image.dispose();

        if (images != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
                images[i].dispose();

        super.dispose();
    }

    protected void paint(Event e) {
        Image image = getCurrentImage();
        if (image == null)
            return;

        GC gc = e.gc;
        gc.drawImage(image, origin.x, origin.y);
        gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
        //gc.setBackground(bg);
        Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
        Rectangle client = getClientArea();
        int marginWidth = client.width - rect.width;
        if (marginWidth > 0) {
            //gc.fillRectangle(rect.width, 0, marginWidth, client.height);
        }
        int marginHeight = client.height - rect.height;
        if (marginHeight > 0) {
            //gc.fillRectangle(0, rect.height, client.width, marginHeight);
        }
    }

    void addListeners() {
        addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                paint(e);
            }
        });
    }

    void convertImageDatasToImages() {
        images = new Image[imageDatas.length];

        // Step 1: Determine the size of the resulting images.
        int width = imageDatas[0].width;
        int height = imageDatas[0].height;

        // Step 2: Construct each image.
        int transition = SWT.DM_FILL_BACKGROUND;
        for (int i = 0; i < imageDatas.length; i++) {
            ImageData id = imageDatas[i];
            images[i] = new Image(display, width, height);
            GC gc = new GC(images[i]);
            gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
            // Do the transition from the previous image.
            switch (transition) {
            case SWT.DM_FILL_NONE:
            case SWT.DM_UNSPECIFIED:
                // Start from last image.
                gc.drawImage(images[i - 1], 0, 0);
                break;
            case SWT.DM_FILL_PREVIOUS:
                // Start from second last image.
                gc.drawImage(images[i - 2], 0, 0);
                break;
            default:
                // DM_FILL_BACKGROUND or anything else,
                // just fill with default background.
                //gc.setBackground(bg);
                //gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                break;
            }

            // Draw the current image and clean up.
            Image img = new Image(display, id);
            gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, id.width, id.height, id.x, id.y, id.width,
                    id.height);
            img.dispose();
            gc.dispose();

            // Compute the next transition.
            // Special case: Can't do DM_FILL_PREVIOUS on the
            // second image since there is no "second last"
            // image to use.
            transition = id.disposalMethod;
            if (i == 0 && transition == SWT.DM_FILL_PREVIOUS)
                transition = SWT.DM_FILL_NONE;
        }
    }

    Image getCurrentImage() {
        if (image != null)
            return image;

        if (images == null)
            return null;

        return images[current];
    }

    void startAnimationTimer() {
        if (images == null || images.length < 2)
            return;

        final int delay = imageDatas[current].delayTime * 10;
        display.timerExec(delay, animationTimer = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (isDisposed())
                    return;

                current = (current + 1) % images.length;
                redraw();

                if (current + 1 == images.length && repeatCount != 0
                        && --repeatCount <= 0)
                    return;
                display.timerExec(delay, this);
            }
        });
    }

    void stopAnimationTimer() {
        if (animationTimer != null)
            display.timerExec(-1, animationTimer);
    }
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Did you ever get transparency working with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, so much work for gif animation..

Anyway, check [Transparency](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency) part of article about [SWT Images](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html), it might help you.